# Is it possible to modify the raid volumes once the OS is installed? RAID10 Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid10, disk-volume

My problem is the following:

I've rented a dedicated server with RAID10, but they have set only one volume in raid -> Disk0.

The Disk0 has 12 Tbs but with MBR i can only use the OS partition 100Gb and another partition of 2Tb.
The remaining 10Tb can't be allocated.

I can't convert that disk0 to GPT.

So... my only option is requesting a new installation with 2 volumes on the RAID? Or there is another way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MBR is limited to 2TB volumes. However GPT is not. Thus there are only two ways to solve it. 1) Many many volumes of 2TB and smaller (ugly,but should work).  2) Reinstall with GPT, you might be able to do this without reinstallation but it does not seem possible while windows is booted from that disk. A live OS CD *might* help here.

Comment: Yes RobM. The server has a hardware RAID10. I'm afraid i'll have to request a reinstallation.